# MySQL two selects but totally different

Tags: php, mysql, select

ok I have to tables they are along the same lines, but one that lists all stores that sell goods and one that is products that we sell.

Think of it like Fruit and Veg totally different.

What I need to work out is if there is 7 fruit and we need 8 listings then go and get a random veg and show it in the same results.

Here is what our query currently looks like. you will notice we can send a $count which we send as 8 but we may want to increase to 10 or even make it 4.

```
public function realcashoffers($state,$count)
{
    $this->state = $state;
    $this->number = $count;
    //print count($this->JSONselect("business_stores","*",NULL,NULL),1);
        print $this->JSONselect("approved_business, business_stores, Real_Cash_Offers"," *, group_concat(offer ORDER BY offer ASC SEPARATOR ',') as offers"," approved_business.id = business_stores.business_id AND  Real_Cash_Offers.business_id = approved_business.id  AND Real_Cash_Offers.storeid = business_stores.storeid AND business_stores.state = '{$this->state}'","GROUP BY id ORDER BY RAND(), approved_business.id DESC LIMIT {$this->number} ");
}
```

this->JSONselect goes to

```
//JSON select
    public function JSONselect($table,$options,$where,$orderby)
    {
        $options = empty($options) ? "*"   : $options;
        $where  =  empty($where)   ? "1=1" : $where;
        $orderby = empty($orderby) ? ""    : $orderby;

        $qry = "SELECT $options FROM $table WHERE $where $orderby ";
        //print $qry;
        $result = mysql_query($qry) or die(json_encode(array("error",mysql_error())));

        while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))){ $resultArray[] = $row; }

        //print json_encode($resultArray);

        return count($resultArray) < 1 ? print "[".json_encode(array("error"=>"sorry"))."]" : json_encode($resultArray);
    }
```

Comment: `realcashoffers("approved_business;drop table approved_business;--","haha pwned");`

Comment: that does not work as we have the settings set that the user name and password can not drop data

Comment: @RussellHarrower - not wanting to take it too far off topic, but an attacker can do a lot of damage without changing your data. Imagine being able to inject something that joins a query to get a username and password from a `users` table, to your existing query. If done cleverly, the attacker may be able to make you print that data to screen.

Comment: @SimonMayer I agree, I have  only had total control over the site for 2 month there is 10,000 lines of code, most of which I am removing and changing to better fit with the new system.

The company that I am working for use to even store bank details and make them puublic when you did a search in the query but did not show them on page. I find it that this is a bigger issue. 

Since taking over we limit the type of a-z and 0-9 and disallow symbioses from = signs to % etc. I do and I agree we have some work to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly I think what your looking for is something along the lines of this;

Update the main function to determine if there were enough results and call the secondary query if not

```
public function realcashoffers($state,$count)
{
     $this->state = $state;
     $this->number = $count;         
     $result = $this->JSONselect("approved_business, business_stores, Real_Cash_Offers"," *, group_concat(offer ORDER BY offer ASC SEPARATOR ',') as offers"," approved_business.id = business_stores.business_id AND  Real_Cash_Offers.business_id = approved_business.id  AND Real_Cash_Offers.storeid = business_stores.storeid AND business_stores.state = '{$this->state}'","GROUP BY id ORDER BY RAND(), approved_business.id DESC LIMIT {$this->number} ");

     $remaining = count($result) - $count;

     if ($remaining) {
        $result = array_merge($result, $this->JSONselect(.. enter secondary call here using $remaining as the limit..);

     }

     $this->JSONprint($result);
}
```

Update JSONselect to return the results instead of being responsible for printing them as well

```
public function JSONselect($table,$options,$where,$orderby)
{
    $resultArray = array();
    $options = empty($options) ? "*"   : $options;
    $where  =  empty($where)   ? "1=1" : $where;
    $orderby = empty($orderby) ? ""    : $orderby;

    $qry = "SELECT $options FROM $table WHERE $where $orderby ";
    //print $qry;
    $result = mysql_query($qry) or die(json_encode(array("error",mysql_error())));

    while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))){ $resultArray[] = $row; }

    //print json_encode($resultArray);

    return $resultArray;
}
```

create JSONprint that will print the results returned

```
protected function JSONprint($resultArray) {
    return count($resultArray) < 1 ? print "[".json_encode(array("error"=>"sorry"))."]" : json_encode($resultArray);
}
```